# Is there a way to get the minimum value for each day in a column of day-time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query that records an individual machine and users that check-in on it at a certain time(day-time). This brings up something like the following.

```
3   2019-07-20 09:54:18.000
3   2019-07-20 09:54:21.000
3   2019-07-20 09:54:25.000
3   2019-07-21 09:51:32.000
3   2019-07-21 09:51:36.000
3   2019-07-21 09:51:43.000
3   2019-07-22 09:41:39.000
3   2019-07-22 09:44:08.000
3   2019-07-22 09:47:27.000
```

where 3 is the machine number and the rest is the time.

My questions is if there is a way of getting the first day-time for each day. something like the following:

```
3   2019-07-20 09:54:18.000
3   2019-07-21 09:51:32.000
3   2019-07-22 09:41:39.000
```

This is the current SQL that creates the query if it helps.

```
SELECT MachineNumber, RecordTime 
from record 
where RecordTime BETWEEN
'2019-07-20T01:00:00.000' AND '2019-07-29T23:59:59.000' AND
MachineNumber = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
MachineNumber, 
MIN(RecordTime) 
FROM your_table
WHERE RecordTime BETWEEN '2019-07-20T01:00:00.000' 
    AND '2019-07-29T23:59:59.000' 
AND MachineNumber = 3
GROUP BY 
MachineNumber,
CAST(RecordTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This logic helped me a lot!

Comment: @pikachungg You are welcome. Please accept the ans and put an up vote if it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY Should give you what you need

```
SELECT MachineNumber, MIN(RecordTime) RecordTime
  from record 
  where RecordTime BETWEEN '2019-07-20T01:00:00.000' AND '2019-07-29T23:59:59.000' AND MachineNumber = 3
  GROUP BY MachineNumber
```

Comment: I tried this, however it only returns me a single day which is the 20th instead of the minimum of each day. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you

```
SELECT
    MachineNumber,
    date(RecordTime) as RecordDate,
    min(RecordTime) as first_record_time_at_day
from
    record
where
    RecordTime BETWEEN  '2019-07-20T01:00:00.000'
                        AND '2019-07-29T23:59:59.000'
    AND MachineNumber = 3
group by
    1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This also worked, but date was not accepted as a function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MachineNumber, date where RecordTime BETWEEN '2019-07-20T01:00:00.000' AND '2019-07-29T23:59:59.000' group by date(RecordTime)
```